# How to create api to start mining in private ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

```
app.post('/start-mining', (req, res) => {
  miner.start(1);
  res.send('Mining started');
  });
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start')

Comment: Mining isn't part of the standard Ethereum interface. You need to send the client and RPC request. For example for geth you have to use `miner_start` https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-miner#miner-start.

Comment: in the backend api the function in web3js miner.start() is not define

Comment: It is a non-standard api, so it isn't part of web3js. I think it should be something like `await provider.send("miner_start");` where `provider` is the instance of your RPC provider.